# How retrieve youtube channel links from "About" section?

Tags: youtube-api

Youtube channels usually have `"About"` section with links to Twitter, facebook acounts etc.
How can I get those links using Youtube API?

Answer (score 1):

If such functionality did exist, it would most likely be under the [`channels`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) resource, which it isn't. Note that some channels don't even fill out the "about" section for their channels. You can try filing a feature request for it on the YouTube issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list) (making sure to add the label `API-YouTube`).